# Destroying a Model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to destroy the following model:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

This is the Item Model

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :department
  belongs_to :job
  belongs_to :category
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

I know I'm going to use `rails d model Job`

but how to delete the column `job_id` in the `Item` Model? is it `db:rollback`?
and how to make sure everything is clean? What else should I do?

Comment: did you write a migration to create the column job_id?

Comment: no that was created from the beginning when I created the model with its relations, will it be automatically deleted?

Comment: Then you have a write the migration to get rid of that row as shown in the answer by @zeantsoi

Comment: shouldn't destroy model, not destroy a model with relations outside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't tell from the information provided whether you can simply run a down migration to removed the `job_id` column, since it might be destructive to other columns. However, you can create a new migration that explicitly deletes the `job_id` column:

```
# from command line
rails g migration RemoveJobIdFromItems
```

Specify the column to remove in your table:

```
def up
  remove_column :items, :job_id
end
```

In case you want to re-add the migration, create a down migrations that rolls back the removal:

```
def down
  add_column :items, :job_id, :integer
end
```

Then run `rake db:migrate` from command line. The column will be removed from the `items` table.

Finally, you'll want to ensure that you've removed the association from your model:

```
# app/models/item.rb
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :department
  belongs_to :category
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

Comment: I did all of that, thanks! why wouldn't destroy model prevent you from deleting a model which has relations?

Comment: It _does_ destroy the model, but it doesn't destroy the relationship in your associated model. That association is created _and_ deleted manually.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just you and you can live without the data in the Item table, then:

- run `rake db:rollback` twice to delete both the Job and Item table
- run `rails d model Job` to delete the Job model and migrations
- edit the Item migration file to manually remove the `belongs_to :job` line
- and finally `rake db:migrate` to get things back to normal

When working with a group, you don't know if they have already ran migrations that added job_id, so this is safer:

- run `rails g migration remove_job_id_from_items job_id:integer` to create a migration that removes job_id from the Item table
- run `rails g migration drop_items_table` to drop the table and edit this migration to add `drop_table :job` to the change block (see note below)
- run `rake db:migrate` to bring those two migrations you just created forward.
- and finally run `rails d model Job --skip-migration` to destroy the model but leave the original migration

When you do it this way, both migrations stay in your project forever, but cancel each other out. In git, we try to only move forward.

(note: this may create an "irreversible migration" and there may be a better way to do this step.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you also put an index on your job_id column, you're going to want to remove that before you remove the column. Also if you're running rails 3.1+ you can skip the up/down methods and just use a change method on something simple like this, otherwise I would completely agree with zeantsoi. For your migration:

```
def change
  remove_index :items, :job_id
  remove_column :items, :job_id
end
```

Also, if your column doesn't have an index: index your foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a migration which will remove the indexed job_id.  No manual migration file modifications needed.  Simply:

```
rails g migration RemoveJobRefFromItems job:references
```